# Downloading empty file

Tags: php

For the life of me I can't see why, but it has the correct file name and all, but the files themselves are empty after download. As far as I can see its going to the correct spot, the database has the correct info too.

```
function download()
{
    global $session,$project,$config,$args;

    $fid = $args[0];
    $query = query('SELECT * FROM files WHERE id = ?',$fid);
    if(num($query) == 1)
    {
        $file = fetch($query);
                    //$happyfix = "http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/admin";
        $filename = URL . "/_files/{$file->in_project}/{$file->in_folder}/" . md5($fid) . ".{$file->extension}";
        //$filename = $happyfix . "/_files/{$file->in_project}/{$file->in_folder}/" . md5($fid) . ".{$file->extension}";
                    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
        {
            ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

        }
        header("Pragma: public"); // required
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
        header("Content-Type: $file->mimetype");
        // change, added quotes to allow spaces in filenames, by Rajkumar Singh
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file->name . '.' . $file->extension."\";" );
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
        readfile("$filename");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('That file does not exist','','error');
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the size of these files? Do you use output-buffering?

Comment: check if the `$filename` string is correct

Comment: If $filename weren't correct, both filesize and readfile would generate a few errors.

Comment: Where would I enter an echo or something else to check $filename? Sorry been out of the loop and just can't remember some things.

Comment: @Helpme just `echo $filename; exit();` before the first header to check the file string

Comment: Sorry, I'm slow, it gives me this:
http://imengine.gofreeserve.com/admin/_files/1/1/c20ad4d76fe97759aa27a0c99bff6710.xls
for the file Accessories Catalog.xls
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You are not sending the headers before sending the file data. Change your last couple lines to add

```
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile("$filename");
```

See the example at http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

Comment: Files are anywhere from 7kb to 400kb, most are like 20 kb though. I tried echo("$filename"); right before readfile, but doesnt do anything. Also added clean and flush, and still empty downloads. I havent messed with php or anything else for a year or so, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
header("Content-Type: $file->mimetype");
```

to:

```
header("Content-Type: {$file->mimetype}");
```